# How do I setup an Office365 e-mail forwarder with federated domain?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have an Office365 subscription with an on premise Active Directory which is connected with ADFS.

I do *not* have an on premise Exchange Server.

I want to setup an e-mail address for my organisation where all e-mail received gets forwarded to another, external e-mail address. As such, we don't want to use an Office365 licence for this.

The instructions to do this appear on this page (under 'Option 2'): http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/exchange/how-to-forward-email-in-office-365.aspx

However, the article states, *"These steps are NOT valid for Hybrid scenarios where an on-premises Active Directory is synchronized with the Office 365 directory.  In that case, you will create the appropriate object type from the Exchange Management Console on premises and let the synchronization occur."*.

The problem is that I don't have the Exchange Management Console!

Can anyone give me some step-by-step instructions that I can use to create an 'Exchange Mail User' that I can setup forwarding for in Office365 (per the article above)?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the answers you were provided help you with your question, you should select one as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Chris,

I'm not sure if you got this resolved, but the link you provided seems to go strange about halfway through it.

Honestly, your easiest bet is to simply create a shared mailbox (info/helpdesk/support/etc.) and set forwarding on that mailbox.

You don't need to use a license for this, it is free.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-suite-help/create-and-use-shared-mailboxes-HA102892906.aspx